# List<id> at IN clause in Dynamic SOQl

Tags: apex, query, list, dynamic-soql, set

I am fetching all the field from sObject and querying using `Database.query()`.
When I query with `List of id's` it is throwing `Invalid ID ('id', 'id', ...)` error.

for example at static soql we can query with list of id's like below

```
select id, name from Account where id in:ids
```

but am getting error when i use in Dynamic SOQL.

Am using below code to fetch and query.

```
    List<id> ids = new List<id>();
    ids.add(...);
    List<Patient__c> paList;
        String query;
        String SobjectApiName = 'Patient__c';
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        String commaSepratedFields = '';
        for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keyset()){
            if(commaSepratedFields == null || commaSepratedFields == ''){
                commaSepratedFields = fieldName;
            }else{
                commaSepratedFields = commaSepratedFields + ', ' + fieldName;
            }
        }

        /////here i want to query with set of id's///

        query = 'select ' + commaSepratedFields + ' from ' + SobjectApiName +' where id='+'\'' + ids + '\'';
        system.debug('=====query===='+query);

       ////error occuring here as INVALID ID ('id','id', .... )////

        paList = Database.query(query);
```

**Problem 1** :How to query the list of id's in dynamic query?

**Problem 2** :I have a Look Up to `Account object(Account is Master)`. When i query like above it is throwing as

> "retrieved soql without querying the requested
>   field:Patient__c.Account__r".

How to Query the lookup relation in Dynamic query.

Thanks

Comment: You should use your list name in the same manner in your dynamic query: `where id=:ids;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple Just use set inside single quote

```
query = 'select ' + commaSepratedFields + ' , from ' + SobjectApiName +' where id IN: ids ';
```

**Edit**

Add `Account__r.Name` field in query

```
query = 'select Account__r.Name, ' + commaSepratedFields + ' , from ' + SobjectApiName +' where id IN: ids ';
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple but forgot. Thanks a lot. I have another error.  I have a lookup to Account in Patient__c object. When I use dynamic query to fetch all the field from Patient__c it is throwing "retrieved SOQL without querying the requested field: Patient__c.Account__r ". How write a query for this?. I'll also update my question for the same.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen check my edit

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen it should be like `Account__r.Name` or other field

Comment: When i add Patient__c.Account__r it is showing No such column in Patient__c. Api Name of the lookup field is Account__c. When I check debug logs without adding Patient__c.Account__r it is retrieving Account__c field too. But when i executing without adding Patient__c.Account__r it is throwing No such column. If I add Patient__c.Account__c in query it is showing Duplicate field is not allowed. Any solution?

Comment: Yep Account__r.Name is the solution. Thanks a lot!!Happy smile

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen Yes correct you need to check which all the field you want access from master Account example Name field the add like `Account__r.Name` if there is other fields then add like that only `Account__r.FieldName`